# Get Position Of XML Node In Original Text

Tags: jquery, xml

is there a way to get the position of a XML node in the original text that it came from? for example:

```
< a>text< /a>

< b>tesxt< /b>
```

then you can see that the `< b>`  tag came from the text at position 11? i kno this might be hard because the DOM can change independent form text but i just want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmlString.indexOf("<b>")`

Comment: it looks like that will give the position in a collection of elements,not an text charater position in original text, so that is not what is good

Comment: what do you mean `<b>` is in position 11?

Comment: it begins at position 11 in the text. it is 11 charaters from begining of text. actualy now it is at 14 i think

Comment: sorry but this is still not what i mean. i already have a jquery object that is the tag i want to kno wthe position. i dont want to know  position of just first b tag or of all b tags, but of a specifc one.

Comment: You have the jquery object that is the tag but not the source xml?  How is that?  Maybe try getting the source xml from `$tagObject.parent().html()`

Comment: i have both source xml and jquery object that is the tag. indexOf does not help in this case. there is more than one b tag.

Comment: Try something like `$tagObject.attr('class', someRandomVar)` and then find the index of `someRandomVar` and subtract however long `class="` is

Comment: is this only way? seems like a hacks

Comment: How else would you know *which* `<b>` to find?  The xml is just a string .. there is nothing unique about it in the xml to indicate which one it is.  You could also find `.index` and keep parsing the string until you reach the indexth `<b>`, but that seems even harder.

Comment: i was thinking maybe jquery kept information about where it got its xml nodes form.